# Does Let's Encrypt have a link to show information about a domain like TrustSign has

Tags: lets-encrypt

In my website I have the let's encrypt logo at the footer to show that my site is secure, in reality I put the the logo there to fill an empty space. I would like to make the image a link so it can be more "useful".

TustSign enables you to access a domain information by using the following link:

https://www.trustsign.com.br/consumidor/selo-ssl?language=pt-br&hostname=www.example.com

Does Let's Encrypt have something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently they don't have something like that.  But you could double check and maybe request the feature here https://community.letsencrypt.org/